# Почему появился зазор между картинкой и границей

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вот пример – https://jsfiddle.net/8qzuq881/1/

Я даже убрал отступы через стили:

```
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
```

Но не помогает. Как убрать зазор?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию браузеры отображают `img` тег как `inline` элемент (например текст), при этом у него есть свойства блока (например `div`), так что его можно относить ближе к элементам типа `inline-block`.

Если рассматривать `img` как `inline` элемент, на примере текста,
то увидим, что текст **по умолчанию** выравнивается по [базовой линии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0)), оставляя пустое пространство под [выносной элемент](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_(%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0)) (например нижняя чать букв `р, д, y`  и т.д.).
Таким образом, в данной ситуации, браузер просто не может точно рассчитать высоту строки.

### Решения:

**1.** Изменяем правило выравнивания (`vertical-align`) на `top` или `bottom`

```
.pre-img img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**2.** Изменяем тип на `block`

```
.pre-img img {
  display: block;
}
```

**3.** Сбрасываем высоту строки родительского контейнера `div.pre-img`

```
.pre-img {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

или

```
.pre-img {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

**4.** "Прикрелииваем" изображение к одной из сторон `float` = `left` или `right`.

```
.pre-img img {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Добавьте `display` на картинку:

```
div.pre-img>img {
  display: block;
}
```

Тогда браузеры будут точно прорисовывать ее размеры.

Answer (score -1):

Некоторые браузеры по умолчанию устанавливают небольшое пространство вокруг основонго содержания страницы

```
body { margin: 0px; }
```