# Возникает ненужный отступ внутри рамки

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/makswolf/g8bpg96x/

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#for_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#img1 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="for_img">
    <img id="img1" src="http://cs623723.vk.me/v623723743/3d20d/o0rLAIda9WU.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Снизу возникает отступ между рамкой и изображением, как его можно убрать?

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1**

Для `#img1` картинки выставить свойство `display` в значение `block`.

**Вариант 2**

Элементу `#for_img` выставить свойства `line-height` и `font-size` в значение `0`.

Comment: Спасибо, а по какой причине вообще появляется этот отступ?

Comment: @maksvolf http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481000/185624